# Django Allauth Custom Login Does Not Show Errors

Tags: python, html, django, django-allauth

I am using Django Allauth for user flow in my project. I have successfully created my own set of templates which inherit from the standard Allauth templates and they work 95%. For some reason, however, I do not receive an error for an invalid login.

If I enter 'test@email' for the user I get a 'Please enter  a valid email address' error but if I enter a proper email with an incorrect password it simply reloads the page but with no errors as to what went wrong. I've included my template below which has the `{{ form.login.errors }}` and `{{ form.password.errors }}` tags.

All guidance is appreciated, thank you.

Template:

```
<div id="search_container">

            <div id="search_box_content">
                {% block page_content %}

                        <h4>Login</h4>

                            <form class="" id="user-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">

                              {% csrf_token %}
                            <h1> {{ form.login.errors }}</h1>
                            <h1> {{ form.password.errors }}</h1>

                               <div class="input_class">

                                    <label for="login">Username: </label>
                            {{ form.login }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="input_class">
                              <label for="password">Password: </label>
                              {{ form.password }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="input_class" id="forgot_pass">
                              <label for="remember">
                              Remember Me? </label>
                            {{ form.remember }}
                            </div>
                              {% if redirect_field_value %}


                              <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                              {% endif %}

                            <div id="modal_bottom_bar">

                              <a class="button secondaryAction" id="forgot_pass" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot your Password?</a>

                              <button class="primaryAction" id="login_submit" type="submit">Login</button></div>
                            </form>

{% endblock %}

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 40):

Some errors are non field errors such as those errors which are raised for some custom validation and are not included in `field.errors` rather they are in `form.non_field_errors`:

So better use this snippet to show all errors which belongs to fields and to custom validation if you are rendering your form manually:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: would give you +10 ;)

Comment: amazing answer, I wish I could give a +10 as well.

Comment: A few messages are not displayed, like 'Too many failed login attempts. Try again later.' How to display this kind of message?

Comment: @cwhisperer Did you figure out how to show  'Too many failed login attempts. Try again later.'?